# C# Creating a class that constructs from an inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class:

```
class Cube
{
   public string Name;
   public string TexturePath;
}
```

And another class that inherits `Cube`

```
class DrawableCube : Cube
{
   public Texture2D Texture;
   public Shader Shader;
}
```

Suppose I have a collection of `Cube` that I want to turn into `DrawableCube`. Without just creating a constructor that takes a `Cube` as an paramter and copies all of the attributes across, how can I make a copy of a `Cube` with the resulting type `DrawableCube`?

Comment: This code is evil, you declare two public members with the same name except for capitalization that are different types...

Comment: I think what you are talking about is the removal of boilerplate. To my knowledge, its not possible to do it without copying all the values over; Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: @mathepic Sorry about that, I typed it in to hastily. Fixed

Comment: @mathepic because I have an array of cubes, and I want to turn them into drawable cubes. Maybe my design is flawed?

Comment: can you not create DrawableCube's in the first place? Or just add the drawable cube stuff to the cube class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO the best solution here is not to inherit `DrawableCube` from `Cube` at all, but let the UI class `DrawableCube` keep an internal reference to the data class `Cube`. `Cube`, however, should probably be designed as an [immutable class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This way `DrawableCube` will need a constructor taking a `Cube`, but you don't have to copy all of it's attributes, you can just store the given reference:

```
class DrawableCube : 
{
   private myCube;

   public DrawableCube(Cube c)
   {
       myCube=c;
   } 
}
```

Comment: A `DrawableCube` is almost certainly a `Cube`, so this breaks OOP polymorphism.

Comment: I think you're right about this. I can probably live without the inheritance here. To Quote GLaDOS in Portal 2, "The best solution is usually the easiest"

Comment: @mathepic: the question to ask here if polymorphism is really needed here for `Cube` and `DrawableCube`. If that's the case, they should have a common base class or interface `ICube`. This will result in the *Proxy design pattern* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), where DrawableCube is a proxy for Cube.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: The following solution is ugly but it does what you want.

Make `Cube` take a single parameter of type `CubeInformation` in its constructor, and that is its only member (it is private). It simply sets the `CubeInformation`. It then provides properties for the stuff in that struct.

Let `CubeInformation` be a struct that contains the data for a `Cube`.

Let `DrawableCube` have a constructor that takes a `Cube` and copies over the `CubeInformation` struct from the `Cube`.

Wallah. If someone has to add more data to the `Cube`, they add it to the `CubeInformation` struct and implement the properties in `Cube`. No maintenance is necessary in `DrawableCube`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn collections of `Cube` into a collections of `DrawableCube`, then maybe inheritance is not the right tool.

Give aggregation a try:

```
class DrawableCube //: Cube
{
   public Cube TheCube { get; private set; }
   public DrawableCube (Cube c) { TheCube = c; }
   public Texture2D Texture;
   public Shader Shader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want a constructor, I guess the only other option is with a factory pattern.

Comment: Well a constructor is fine, but I don't want to manually copy the values across. (What if someone decides to add new fields to cube?)

Comment: Your whole design seems to be the problem.

Comment: Do you think I should do this without inheritance then, and create a DrawableCube class that just contains a Cube?

Comment: Why do you need to separate "Cube" and "DrawableCube"?

Comment: Because Cube comes from another assembly, which can't have a reference to OpenGL.